# xenforo login authentication software

Tags: java, encryption, forum, password-encryption, xenforo

I want to create a third party login application and for that I need to match the hash of password to the one entered by the user. as far as I know xenforo use

```
sha1(sha1(password) . salt)
or:
sha256(sha256(password) . salt)
```

**but how can I achieve the same encryption in my java program.** I found some answers like using

```
$password = substr($password, 22, -3);
```

but this doesn't work now. ***For those who want to know the encryption method used by xenforo then here the code***

```
protected $_data = array();

/**
* Hash function to use for generating salts and passwords
*
* @var string
*/
protected $_hashFunc = '';

/**
* Setup the hash function
*/
protected function _setupHash()
{
    if ($this->_hashFunc)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (extension_loaded('hash'))
    {
        $this->_hashFunc = 'sha256';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_hashFunc = 'sha1';
    }
}

/**
* Perform the hashing based on the function set
*
* @param string
*
* @return string The new hashed string
*/
protected function _createHash($data)
{
    $this->_setupHash();
    switch ($this->_hashFunc)
    {
        case 'sha256':
            return hash('sha256', $data);
        case 'sha1':
            return sha1($data);
        default:
            throw new XenForo_Exception("Unknown hash type");
    }
}

protected function _newPassword($password, $salt)
{
    $hash = $this->_createHash($this->_createHash($password) . $salt);
    return array('hash' => $hash, 'salt' => $salt, 'hashFunc' => $this->_hashFunc);
}

/**
* Initialize data for the authentication object.
*
* @param string   Binary data from the database
*/
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->_data = unserialize($data);
    $this->_hashFunc = $this->_data['hashFunc'];
}

/**
* Generate new authentication data
* @see XenForo_Authentication_Abstract::generate()
*/
public function generate($password)
{
    if (!is_string($password) || $password === '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    $salt = $this->_createHash(self::generateSalt());
    $data = $this->_newPassword($password, $salt);
    return serialize($data);
}

/**
* Authenticate against the given password
* @see XenForo_Authentication_Abstract::authenticate()
*/
public function authenticate($userId, $password)
{
    if (!is_string($password) || $password === '' || empty($this->_data))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $userHash = $this->_createHash($this->_createHash($password) . $this->_data['salt']);
    return ($userHash === $this->_data['hash']);
}
```